# How do the ">" and "<" operators work for string comparisons?

Tags: c++, string

In the C++ textbook I'm reading (*Programming, Principles and Practice using C++* by Bjarne Stroustrup), there are numerous instances of code snippets in which strings are compared as follows:
`if (str1 > str2)` and then some code.

Could someone please explain to me how "bigger than" and "less than" operators work in conjunction with strings declared as follows:

```
#include <string>
.
.
.
string str1 = "foo";
string str2 = "bar";
```

I've tried searching on Stack Overflow and on others for this answer, but to no avail.

Comment: The operators (which, BTW, are removed in the C++20 standard) use lexicographical comparison: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp - Note that many of these have been removed in C++20.

Comment: @AdrianMole The operators themselves are removed, but expressions like `str1 > str2` remain valid with the addition of `<=>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strings are compared lexicographically . The string in which an character is lexicographically greater than the corresponding character in other string will be considered as the greater string. This is known as **[lexicographical comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).**

> The lexicographic or lexicographical order (also known
>   as lexical order, dictionary order, alphabetical order or
>   lexicographic(al) product) is a generalization of the way words are
>   alphabetically ordered based on the alphabetical order of their
>   component letters.

You can use the `.compare()` method as well to compare two strings . It will return the following values -

> 0 : They compare equal
>
> Less than 0 : Either the value of the first character that does not
>   match is lower in the compared string, or all compared characters
>   match but the compared string is shorter.
>
> more than 0 : Either the value of the first character that does not
>   match is greater in the compared string, or all compared characters
>   match but the compared string is longer.

On the contrary, the relational operators (like `>`, `<`, `==`) will return only boolean values true of false. In the expression `str1 < str2` , str1 will be smaller than str2 if first mismatched character in str1 is smaller than the corresponding  character in str2. If all characters match, `str1` will be less than `str2` only if its length is shorter.

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think the Standard requires that characters are encoded in ASCII representation.

Answer (score 3):

Relational operators on strings estabilish so-called [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). It's the same ordering as used in the dictionaries.

Here's the algorithm: to determine if `a` is less than `b`, you need to find the smallest `i` so that `a[i] != b[i]`, and if `(unsigned char)a[i] < (unsigned char)b[i]`, then `a < b`, otherwise `a > b`.

If there is no such `i`, then `a == b`.

If `a` is a prefix of `b`, then `a < b` (this follows from the algorithm above, if you consider the extra `\0` at the end of a string to be a part of the string).

Comment: @Artyer I didn't say that `\0` terminates a string. My point was that for the purpose of this algorithm, the extra `\0` at the end of a string counts a part of the string. Edited to make this more clear.